# Two independent standard normal distribution X, Y. What is the value of x if $Pr( X>Y and X\geq x)=3/8$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

$X$, $Y$ are two independent standard normal distribution. I know that $Pr(X>Y)=1/2$. But I have no idea about how to calculate the value of $x$, if $Pr( X>Y, X\geq x)=3/8$.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context and read through the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that $$Pr( X>Y, X\geq x)=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{t=\max\{x,y\}}^\infty e^{-\frac 12(t^2+y^2)} dt dy,$$ but the value of $x$ such that the probability equals $3/8$ has to be found approximately, via tables, for instance.

Comment: I thought it should be $$Pr(X>Y, X \ge x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{x}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{t}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(t^2+y^2)}dydt$$. But I have no idea how to get the exact value of $x$

Comment: @Samson This is integration of the same function $e^{-\frac 12(t^2+y^2)}$ over the same domain $\{(t,y): t\ge\max\{x,y\}\}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you, Alex. All bests,